# Heroku rails installation stopped working after month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I set up this super simple rails app about 5 month ago and it worked until lately.

But today i noticed im getting this error: "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

I checked the heroku logs but i dont see any errors appart from what i assume is the daily restart:

```
2017-02-11T01:37:52.624288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=url.herokuapp.com request_id=918be0b7-bf45-4111-97b8-d95450dd3507     fwd="126.7.114.122" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
2017-02-11T01:38:45.926088+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-02-11T01:38:45.927276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437082+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-11 01:38:46] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437099+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437100+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in start'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437101+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437102+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437103+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437103+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437104+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437105+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437105+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437106+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437106+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437107+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437108+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437109+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437176+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-11 01:38:46] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2017-02-11T01:38:46.437226+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-11 01:38:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

I also took a look at my production.log file but it's weirdly empty.

I'm at a loss regarding how to trouble shoot this. any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with this error output. can you try heroku logs -n 1500 and post the output of what actually causes the error? Thx

Comment: Yes, I have but I couldnt find any useful information there. 
But I actually found what was going on. I will post an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out it wasnt actually related to the environment.

I ran the site on my machine with the prod env and was able to find an access_token was expired which error wasnt caught correctly causing the 500 error. 
I fixed it and redeployed the site. it works now.